# Filter applications which can send standard notification

Tags: android

How can I filter among the Applications as which applications send Notifications.
I can get a list of all installed applications

Now I want to filter out only those applications which are sending Notifications to Notification Bar.
I know any application can send notification but still if there is some way to find out,Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible because showing notification does not require any special permission or tag inside manifest that can be queried from system.